# AWS Access and Secret Keys in Terraform code with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

Instead of passing the Access and Secret keys in variables.tf of Terraform code,is there any safe and secure method of passing the keys to the code when Jenkins Pipeline is deployed??
The pipeline will be re-deployed often and the keys should be passed everytime.

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/ 
You can use this feature to store the keys.

Comment: @ Ash Blake Thanks for the response. I will look into it. Is there any other method  that the code takes the keys directly from AWS??

Comment: Of course, you can use the aws cli in the jenkins pipeline to get the keys. Or you can create a default user and assume the role to deploy

Comment: @ Ash Blake Can you explain in detail please

Comment: I will explain in the answer section cause it includes code

Comment: If jenkins is running in aws, you can use the instance profile of the jenkins server to retrieve values from ssm parameter store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to store a default credentials in your host to execute some awscli. You can do something like this:

```
sh "mkdir -p ~/.aws"
sh "cd ~/.aws; rm -rf credentials"
sh "cd ~/.aws; cp credentials-default credentials
```

In your AWS IAM section, you need to give the default credentials permissions to assume the role you need by command

```
aws sts assume-role ... > test.txt
```

In the test.txt file is the credentials with the temporary access and secret key for that session.

You can refer this documents for the above option: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to store any aws credentials on Jenkins best way would be create a Jenkins slave on EC2 instance and attach the required IAM roles to that instance. This way you don’t have to store or predefine any secret id and access key in Jenkins credential manager or Jenkins nodes